# Finding a friend of a friend of a friend

Tags: algorithm, search, depth-first-search, breadth-first-search

Say I have a user object that contains a friends property. This friends property is an array of other user objects and therefor are your friends. What would be the fastest algorithm to find friends of your friends that are not your friends, and then one step further, finding friends of your friend's friends that are both not your friends and your friend's friends.

Here's an example in case the above was confusing:

Bob is friends with Ryan.
Ryan is friends with Jacob.
Jacob is friends with Harry.
Bob is not friends with Jacob.
Bob is not friends with Harry.
Ryan is not friends with Harry.
Jacob qualifies as a friend of a friend.
Harry qualifies as a friend of a friend of a friend.

I'm thinking a BFS but I'm curious to see if anyone else has every tackled a problem like this?

Comment: if your `friend of a friend of a friend` is also your `friend`, do you want to add him  to the result or not?

Answer (score 0):

I think a BFS approach would be best in this problem.

Let's take a look at this simple friend tree:

```
             David
           /
       Bob
     /     \ 
    /        Carl
Adam         
    \        Jim
     \     /
      Carl 
           \
             Sam
```

If we were to take a DFS approach to this problem, we would first traverse Bob and see that he is friends with David and Carl. Since we took a DFS approach to this problem, we do not yet know that Carl is an immediate friend of Adam.

If we had taken a BFS approach, we would be able to determine if the friends of Bob are already friends of Adam.

Answer (score 0):

I'm thinking that this can be done with a filter and a three-level loop:

```
friends = user.friends        # first- or second-level friends
friends3 = []                 # third-level friends
for friend in user.friends:
    for friend2 in friend.friends:    # friends of friends
        if friend2 not in friends:    # filter out existing friends
            friends.add(friend2)
            for friend3 in friend2.friends:    # friends of friends of friends
                if friend3 not in friends:     # filter out existing friends (of friends)
                    friends3.add(friend3)      # these match the criteria
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int levels = 3;
HashSet<User>[] friendsPerLevel = new HashSet<User>[levels];

// set the 0 level with your immediate friends
friendsPerLevel[0] = new HashSet<User>(currentUser.Friends);

// fill the rest of the levels
for(int i = 1; i < levels; i++) {
  friendsPerLevel[i] = new HashSet<User>();

  // get all friends from the previous level
  foreach(User previousFriend in friendsPerLevel[i - 1]) {

    // loop through their friends list
    foreach(User friend in previousFriend.Friends) {

      // check if friend already exists in previous levels
      bool exists = false;
      for(int j = 0; j < i; j++) {
        if(friendsPerLevel[j].Contains(friend)) {
          exists = true;
          break;
        }
      }

      // add the new friend
      if(exists == false) {
        friendsPerLevel[i].Add(friend)
      }
    }
  }
}
```